# Restrict ssh access per user based on conditions

Tags: shell, ssh, sftp

Is there a way to restrict a user to only use ssh to connect via SFTP, but disallow that same user to login to a secure shell terminal?  I only want the user to have the ability to connect by an SFTP client and nothing else.

Comment: You can take at - http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/chroot-sftp-setup/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, have a look at [Ubuntu SFTP-Only Account How-to](http://solderintheveins.co.uk/2011/03/ubuntu-sftp-only-account-how-to/):

> 1. Step 1- Create a Group for the Restricted Accounts
>
>    For the sake of this example, we’ll create a new group called
>      ‘sftponly‘ It’s best to use the addgroup command to do this, as it
>      takes care of allocating an un-used GID (Group Identifier) to the new
>      group for us:
>
>    ```
>    sudo addgroup sftponly
>    ```
> 2. Step 2- Create the User Account
>
>    For examples sake, we’ll create a user account with the username ‘bob‘
>      , set his home directory as ‘/home/bob‘ and give him the password
>      ‘pass‘
>
>    We’ll use the useradd command here as it takes care of assigning an
>      unallocated UID to the user account for us.
>
>    Creating the User Account:
>
>    ```
>    sudo useradd -d /home/bob -s /usr/lib/sftp-server -M -N -g sftponly bob
>    ```
>
>    Setting the Password:
>
>    ```
>    sudo passwd bob
>    ```
> 3. Step 3- Setup the users home directory
>
>    Right, lets create a home for bob and give him somewhere to put his
>      files. Enter the commands below one by one on separate lines:
>
>    ```
>      sudo mkdir -p /home/bob/uploads /home/bob/.ssh 
>      sudo chown bob:sftponly /home/bob/uploads /home/bob/.ssh 
>      sudo chmod 700 /home/bob/.ssh
>    ```
>
>    The first line creates the ‘/home/bob‘, /home/bob/uploads‘ and
>      ‘/home/bob/.ssh‘ directories.
>
>    The second line sets the owner and group of the /home/bob directory to
>      root. This is an important step as the SSH server will complain (and
>      refuse to let our restricted user login) if the root of the users home
>      directory is NOT owned by root.
>
>    The third line sets the owner and group on ‘/home/bob/uploads‘ and ‘
>      /home/bob/.ssh‘ so these directories can be used by the restricted
>      user. In this example, the ‘uploads‘ subdirectory will be used to
>      store files while the ‘.ssh‘ subdirectory is used to store the users
>      public key.
>
>    You should be able to login to you account with a username and
>      password when you’ve completed all the steps in this guide, but it’s
>      recommended you use the public key method for authentication as it is
>      considerably more secure.
>
>    If you already have a private and public key you would like to use,
>      then all you need to do is to upload a copy of the public key to a
>      subdirectory named .ssh in the users home directory.
>
>    Assuming that our public key file is named ‘bob.pub‘, we would issue
>      the following commands to setup public key authentication for the bob
>      user account.
>
>    ```
>    cd /home/bob/.ssh cat bob.pub >> authorized_keys 
>    chmod 700 authorized_keys 
>    chown bob:sftponly authorized_keys 
>    rm -r bob.pub
>    ```
> 4. Step 4- Add an entry to /etc/shells
>
>    Open the file /etc/shells as root in your favorite text-editor, and
>      add the following line at the bottom:
>
>    ```
>    /usr/lib/sftp-server
>    ```
> 5. Step 5- Amend the SSH Server Configuration file
>
>    Open the SSH server configuration file as root to start making
>      changes. On a Ubuntu system, this file is usually /etc/ssh/sshd_config
>      This may differ with other distributions, so check beforehand.
>
>    Find the line `Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` and change
>      it to read:
>
>    ```
>    Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
>    ```
>
>    Now add the following lines at the bottom of the file:
>
>    ```
>    Match group sftponly
>    ChrootDirectory %h
>    X11Forwarding no
>    AllowTcpForwarding no
>    ForceCommand internal-sftp
>    ```
>
>    The line `Match group sftponly` tells the SSH server to apply the
>      configuration options below it to all members of the `sftponly` system
>      group.
>
>    The line `ChrootDirectory %h` tells the SSH server to confine a user to
>      their home directory only (The home directory is specified here using
>      `%h`)
>
>    The `X11Forwarding no` and `AllowTcpForwarding no` lines prevent the
>      user from, respectively, accessing graphical applications on the
>      server and from connecting to other systems via ours.
>
>    The `ForceCommand internal-sftp` line prevents the user from
>      executing their own commands and forces them to use the SFTP server
>      component of the SSH server by executing the ‘internal-sftp‘ command
>      when the user logs in.
> 6. Step 6- Restart the SSH Server
>
>    Ubuntu/Debian users can issue the following command to restart the SSH
>      server:
>
>    ```
>    sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
>    ```
>
> That’s it. You should be able to login using the ‘sftp‘ command with
>   either the username and password you setup or using your private key
>   (if you set this up in Step 2.) Using the setup outlined here, you
>   would only have to repeat steps 1-3 to setup new accounts.

Comment: Well that was easy enough.

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Next time, copy the relevant information here as I did. That way, i) the answer is _here_ and not off-site and ii) the answer is not dependent on the link working next year. Normally, such answers are deleted on sight. I left this one and edited it only because it had been accepted.

Comment: @terdon I take it you have authors consent to reproduce their work here.

Comment: @arober11 I have clearly shown it to be a quote, and I give attribution. This is the best I could do given that the OP had accepted your answer. The Right Way® would be to summarize/rephrase the article in a way that someone reading your answer would be able to reproduce it. You then give the link as a reference. I came here to delete the answer (which had been correctly flagged as "not an answer") and found that it had been accepted, so I did what I could. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/203101) for the SE policy on link-only answers.

Comment: @terdon Please note this is a commercial site; pasting in more than a sentence or two of someone else's work, even if quoted, may go beyond any ***fair use*** copyright exemption.

Comment: @arober11 Huh? The content is copied in away that 1) highlights the fact that it's a quote and ii) provided clear attribution. Is this perfect? No. But given that you had already posted a link as an answer and that the OP had accepted, it was the best I could do. Next time, as I said, please take the time to post an actual _answer_ that explains what is needed instead of posting a link to some other site. That way, we can avoid the whole business. If the original author has a problem with this, I'll be happy to remove it and will ask an SE employee to just delete your answer.

Comment: @arober11 I don't see this `The second line sets the owner and group of the /home/bob directory to root.` in the second steps perhaps I am missing something?